# Display contents of NSDictionary in NSOutlineView and update this data

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsdictionary, nsoutlineview

I need to display the content of a `NSDictionary` in a `NSOutlineView`.
I do this by using a struct that holds my data and which is used by my `NSOutlineView` as DataSource.

```
struct DataItem {
    var caption : String
    var text : String
}

dataInOutlineView: [DataItem]
```

I loop over all my items in my `NSDictionary` and add them to my data array

```
data.append(DataItem(caption: "KeyFromDict", text: "TextFromDict"))
```

And then I reload my `NSOutlineView`

```
outlineView.reloadData()
```

This concept works find but my problem is, that the data inside the `NSDictionary` changes regularly and I want to display the updated values in the `NSOutlineView`.

My first attempt was to remove all items from the array

```
 data.removeAll
```

Then added the data again using the method above and then reload the `NSOutlineView` again but this results in a complete refresh of the `NSOutlineView` which means that all expanded items are collapsed again and the `NSOutlineView` is scrolled to top.

What would be a better idea to realize this? (if not is there a way to update the data using the method above but remain all expanded/collapsed and scroll location state?)

Thanks!

Comment: Replacing the data replaces the content of the outline view. If you want to update the content then update the data. See [NSOutlineView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsoutlineview) "Each item in the outline view must be unique. In order for the collapsed state to remain consistent between reloads the item's pointer must remain the same and the item must maintain isEqual(_:) sameness."

Comment: Ok, but how would some do this? Creating a timer inside the DataItem which reads the content of one specific element?

Comment: Instead of `data.removeAll` loop over the items in the `NSDictionary` and update them in the data array.

Comment: If you can't keep the pointers intact, you can just save the collapsed sections and scroll view bounds before loading the data, and then setting those again. In Objective C you would set `NSPoint scrollPosition = scrollView.contentView.bounds.origin;`, then reload data and call `[scrollView.contentView scrollPoint:scrollPosition];`